# grep: unescaped ^ or $ not supported with -Pz

Tags: regex, bash, shell, grep

I wonder why in the new version of grep (Ubuntu 16.04) my bash script stopped working:

```
...
COMMIT_REGEX='^\[[A-Z]+-[0-9]+\] \s*\S+(?:.|\n|\r)*\s* \(review: ([a-z]+\.[a-z]+|MYSELF)\)$'

if ! grep -Paz "$COMMIT_REGEX" "$1"; then
...
```

I get "grep: unescaped ^ or $ not supported with -Pz". I've tried to escape ^ and $ symbols, but it doesn't help.

In Ubuntu 15.10 script works perfectly.

Comment: The man page mentions: `-P  ... This is highly experimental ... `

Comment: The release notes of version 2.24 mention the options `-z` and `-Pz` and a bugfix in context with `^` and `$` :  http://savannah.gnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=8477

Comment: can you try to escape it with `COMMIT_REGEX='\^......`?

Comment: @incBrain that would make them the litteral characters `^$` rather than the meta-character representing the start and end of lines

Comment: I'm wondering why you need to use `-P` at all? Is it just for the non-capturing group? I guess it doesn't really matter if it captures, so you could just try using a regular group.

Comment: @Aaron the shorthands work with GNU grep anyway regardless of the regex mode (I assume that's what the OP is using).

Comment: @Aaron I thought that maybe with `-P` option there is kind of hack to overcome this. [bug2265](https://www.mail-archive.com/bug-grep@gnu.org/msg06182.html)

Comment: @TomFenech oh, I guess I was thinking about `sed` then. I tested it and it indeed works.

Comment: @Aaron as far as I know, modern-ish GNU versions of either tool work. Try `grep -q '\w' <<<'a' && echo yes` or `sed 's/\w/b/' <<<'a'`.

Comment: @TomFenech godammit, will you stop being right?! ;) That's strange though, I vividly remember having to translate all my shorthand classes to a longer version recently with some linux tool.

Comment: @Aaron :) they're not supported by Bash's built-in regexes, so maybe that's what you were thinking of.

Comment: @TomFenech that might be it. I won't hesitate to use classes shorthands any longer at least, I thank you for that!

Comment: I'd argue that you were better off with your prior instinct of hesitating. There are lots of non-GNUish tools out there. MacOS, FreeBSD, OpenBSD, Busybox... stick with things that the POSIX standard guarantees will work with `grep -E` and you don't have to guess where your users will be.

Comment: @TomFenech, I have only experience with PCRE in PHP, so I've chosen P-mode as I'm not familiar with peculiarity of others.

Comment: @LarsFischer, thanks a lot, I should have checked grep changelog first :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the problem is the result of a [bug with `grep -Pz`](http://savannah.gnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=8477) (credit to [Lars Fischer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4086774/lars-fischer) for finding the relevant report).

I would suggest dropping the `-P` switch and using `-E` instead:

```
commit_re='^\[[A-Z]+-[0-9]+\] \s*\S+(.|\n|\r)*\s* \(review: ([a-z]+\.[a-z]+|MYSELF)\)$'

if ! grep -qEaz "$commit_re" "$1"; then
```

The only changes that I've made are to change `-P` to `-E` and add the `-q` (quiet) switch, since you're only interested in the return code. You don't really need a non-capturing group, so I changed it to a normal one.

I also don't like to see ALL_CAPS variable names as they should really be reserved for use by the shell.